# How do I combine effectful event handlers and custom EventUpdates in purescript-halogen?

Tags: purescript, halogen

In my custom Halogen/Purescript project I follow the pattern from the [AJAX Example](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/9d2348a4eb42eace19ecec2b5c7af224cbcb30ed/examples/ajax/Main.purs#L79) where I split my actions up into pure `Input`s and effectful `Request`s.

I want to change my event handler to use the `preventDefault` behavior, but don't understand what consequences for the type of the UI function this entails.

I made the same changes to the AJAX Example by changing the event handler the following way:

Before:

```
H.button [ A.classes [B.btn, B.btnPrimary]
         , A.disabled busy
         , A.onclick (\_ -> pure (handler code))
         ] [ H.text "Compile" ]
```

After:

```
H.a [ A.classes [B.btn, B.btnPrimary]
    , A.href "#compile"
    , A.disabled busy
    , A.onclick (\_ -> E.preventDefault $> pure (handler code))
    ] [ H.text "Compile" ]
```

(Full diff available [here](https://github.com/passy/purescript-halogen/commit/7bc447b009fde5fbdbafe4f0e8a2fbe896b0ca68))

I end up with this type error:

```
Cannot unify type
    Example.Ajax.Input
    with type
        Halogen.HTML.Events.Monad.Event Halogen.HalogenEffects<(http ::
        Example.Ajax.HTTP | u32519)> Example.Ajax.Input
```

At this point, I'm a bit lost whether I would need to adjust the type signature of the UI function or I apply the `preventDefault` modifier the wrong way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `$>` looks like:

```
($>) :: forall a. EventHandler a -> b -> EventHandler b
```

The type of `pure` looks like:

```
pure :: forall a. a -> EventHandler a
```

So the problem is by using both together, you're making a type which looks like this:

```
EventHandler a -> EventHandler b -> EventHandler (EventHandler b)
```

But you don't want that, you just want an `EventHandler b`, where `b` is the `E.Event` type of `handler code`.

The best solution is to just not use `pure`:

```
E.preventDefault $> handler code
```

If sometime you do have two `EventHandler` values you want to use together like this, the function to use is `*>` instead of `$>`.

Comment: That was fantastic. You actually answered the question I really should have ask: What do the concrete signatures of the generic types I'm dealing with look like? Thank you so much!